# Issue with Mermaid Diagram Styles: Styling Not Working Properly

Tags: css, charts, diagram, flowchart, mermaid

I am currently working on creating a flowchart using Mermaid syntax, and I'm facing some issues with the styling of the subgraph. I have defined a style for the "Build Process" subgraph using `style buildStyle`, and a style for the subgraph title using `classDef buildTitleStyle`. However, it seems that the styles are not being applied correctly.

Here is the relevant part of my Mermaid code:

```
graph TB

    subgraph "Build Process"
        style buildStyle fill:#F2DEDE,stroke:#A94442,stroke-width:2px
        classDef buildTitleStyle fill:#F2DEDE,font-weight:bold,font-style:italic
        A(Start)
        A -- Build --> B(Docker Image)
        B -- Read --> C(Dockerfile)
        C -- Pull --> D(Base Image)
        D -- Copy --> E(Project Files)
        E -- Install Dependencies --> F[Build Complete]
        F -- End --> H(End Build)
    end

    subgraph "Documentation Generation"
        style docsStyle fill:#DFF0D8,stroke:#3C763D,stroke-width:2px
        classDef docsTitleStyle fill:#DFF0D8,font-weight:bold,font-style:italic
        H --> G(Start Container)
        G -- Check DOCS_EXTRA --> I{DOCS_EXTRA?}
        I -- True --> J[Install Extra Dependencies]
        I -- False --> K[Skip Extra Dependencies]
        J -- Generate Documentation --> L('docs/build')
        K -- Generate Documentation --> L
        L -- Stop --> M[Process Complete]
    end

    class A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M buildTitleStyle
    class H,I,J,K,L,M docsTitleStyle
```

Despite defining the buildStyle and buildTitleStyle, the subgraph is not being filled with the specified color, and the subgraph title is not appearing in bold and italic as intended.

I have tried various approaches, but I'm unable to identify what might be causing this issue. Any help or insights on why the styles are not working properly would be greatly appreciated.